# Show that the language is regular modifying the DFA

Tags: regular-language

Let L be a regular language. How can I show that the language $\text{Suffix}(L)=\{w
 \in \Sigma^* \mid \text{ there is a $x \in \Sigma^*$ so that }xw \in L\}$ is also regular? How can I modify the DFA of $L$ so that it accepts $\text{Suffix}(L)$.

Comment: Do you mean $\text{Suffix}(L) = \{w\ |\ \exists x (xw\in L)\}$? The way you have defined it above it is just $L$...

Comment: Yes,that is what I mean...

Answer (score 1):

The "easy" way to do this is to use the equivalence of NFAs and DFAs.  Let the DFA that accepts $L$ be $M$.  First, make an NFA $M_s$ whose start state has $\varepsilon$-transitions to every state of $M$ that is accessible from $M$'s start state.  (And otherwise $M_s$ has the same states as $M$.)  It is not hard to check that $M_s$ accepts Suffix$(L)$.  Then one can convert the NFA $M_s$ into a DFA accepting the same language in a canonical way by using the powerset construction.

I'm not sure that there is a simpler direct construction.

Comment: Perfectly good answer (+1). I wonder why the downvote?

Comment: @Rick: There’s been a minor epidemic of them recently. I’m getting hit with a couple on correct answers just about every day.

Comment: @Brian. So I understand from meta. Seems like a bootless protest (if indeed it is) to me.